# STS: Different "view" of Packages in Spring MVC vs Spring Roo - Project

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm just starting with having fun with Spring Roo...
Everything is nice so far. But eclipse (STS) sometimes behaves strage.

If i generate a new Spring MVC-Project, the containing Packages are shown as I'm familiar with, in eclipse.

If i generate a Roo-Project, Eclipse just shows the Package-Folders.

How can i fix this?

[image: MVC-Projects have the Package-View. Roo-Projects don't]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by configuring your Eclipse project to contain Roo generated folder `src` as an Eclipse Source Folder.

For more information and how to, please see the following article.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=367962

Figure 6-1 is the dialog where you should add your Source folder.

Cheers!